# Why a warning of "control reaches end of non-void function" for the main function?

Tags: c

I run the following C codes and got a warning: control reaches end of non-void function

```
int main(void) {}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: There is a diagnostic bug in g++ 9.4.0 that erroneously points to an RAII class with this error.  The same issue exist, but at the end of the function. Ubuntu 20.04 g++ 9.4.0 exhibits and Ubuntu 22.04 11.2.0 has fixed it.  I could not replicate on godbolt with a minimal example, so not sure of the actual triggering conditions.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just put `return 0` in your `main()`. Your function main returns an int (`int main(void)`) therefore you should add a return in the end of it.

Control reaches the end of a non-void function

```
Problem: I received the following warning:
```

**warning**: control reaches end of non-void function

Solution: This warning is similar to the warning described in Return with no value. If control reaches the end of a function and no return is encountered, GCC assumes a return with no return value. However, for this, the function requires a return value. At the end of the function, add a return statement that returns a suitable return value, even if control never reaches there.

[source](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/tpfhelp/current/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.ztpf-ztpfdf.doc_put.cur/gtpm1/m1rhnvf.html)

**Solution**:

```
int main(void)
{
    my_strcpy(strB, strA);
    puts(strB);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

As an alternative to the obvious solution of adding a `return` statement to `main()`, you can use a C99 compiler (“gcc -std=c99” if you are using GCC).

In C99 it is legal for `main()` not to have a `return` statement, and then the final `}` implicitly returns 0.

```
$ gcc -c -Wall t.c
t.c: In function ‘main’:
t.c:20: warning: control reaches end of non-void function
$ gcc -c -Wall -std=c99 t.c
$
```

---

A note that purists would consider important: you should **not** fix the warning by declaring `main()` as returning type `void`.

Answer (score 3):

The main function has a return-type of int, as indicated in

```
int main(void)
```

however your main function does not return anything, it closes after

```
puts(strB);
```

Add

```
return 0;
```

after that and it will work.