# Why do I get the warning 'control reaches end of non-void function' even when the return is guaranteed

Tags: c

I understand that, given the code never enters the loop, would give me the error.
However, given that `r` is equal to `1`, it should return it, *i.e.*, it would always enter it.

```
int arroz() {

    int r = 1;
    while (r) {
        return r;
    }
}
```

So, why does this code give me the warning control reaches end of non-void function?

Comment: Static analysis reduces to solving the halting problem so false positives can occur.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why a warning of "control reaches end of non-void function" for the main function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13464243/why-a-warning-of-control-reaches-end-of-non-void-function-for-the-main-functio)

Comment: Your compiler is not aware that the loop **always** returns and warns about the (im)possible code path to the final `}` of the function.

Comment: It's because there is no return for the function, even though, with the given conditions, it will never be reached.  After adding e.g. `return 0` you might then see a warning about *unreachable code* ;)

Comment: @Den-Jason no, that does not answer, because `main` in C does not need to return a value any more!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler correctly assumes that `r` is a variable value, it does not process it as a constant, that being the case it cannot be sure what the value is going to be and therefore if the body of the cycle will or will not be executed.

If you use a constant the warning goes away because the compiler will assemble the code using a constant value.

You can check this behavior [here](https://godbolt.org/z/8vMEbx).

Comment: IMO it is a bug. variable is not volatile and it cannot be "variable"

Comment: @P__J__ Not my DV, but volatile will assure the variable is not optimized, the lack of volatile qualification does not assure the variable is optimized. In any case, if it's a bug, it's also in clang and msvc, so it doesn't look like it. In many situations you only get a constant if you compile with optimizations enabled.

Comment: `but volatile will assure the variable is not optimized` no, `volatile` means something different. It says compiler that this variable is side effect prone - ie it can be modified by something outside the normal execution path. In this case for example it could be changed from 1 to zero by something. In this case, warning makes sense.

Comment: In this example, nothing can change it from one to zero and there are  no another execution paths which may avoid the `return` statement

Comment: @P__J__, I'm not saying that's what it means, I'm saying that it's the practical effect of having `volatile` qualification. Your assessment in this regard is accurate, "An object that has volatile-qualified type may be modified in ways unknown to the implementation or have other unknown side effects", therefore it cannot be optimized.

Comment: ***`therefore it cannot be optimized`*** it is going farther than only this. here you have an example: https://godbolt.org/z/Y4K597 https://godbolt.org/z/hnT8v1

Answer (score -1):

IMO it is a bug in the compiler. The analyzer should see that there is no execution path avoiding the `return` statement. The variable is not `volatile`.

The code is compiled to:

```
arroz:                                  # @arroz
        mov     eax, 1
        ret
```

This shows that compiler know that it will always return 1

You should report the bug.